SVG Text Won't Scale
I'm trying to use css animations on some SVG text and for some reason the scale() property isn't working.  This is how I have it set up.
<text class="profession_title" x="144" y="72" text-anchor="middle">
    Full Stack Developer
</text>

In my stylesheet I have the following code
.profession_title{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: hsl(var(--gray-300), 1);
    transform: translateY(30px);
    opacity: 0;
    /*transform: scale(.6, 1.4);*/
    transform-origin: center;
    animation: workTitleAnimationSequence 300ms ease-in forwards;
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes workTitleAnimationSequence{
    from{ opacity: 0; transform: translateY(30px); }
    to{ opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
}

The animation works, however if you notice I have transform: scale(.6, 1.4); commented out.  That didn't have any effect on my text so I tried adding it directly to the text element as <text transform="scale(.6, 1.4)"> to see if that would work and it didn't.  I ultimately want to do something like this:
@keyframes workTitleAnimationSequence{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(30px) scale(.6, 1.4);
    }
    96%{
        transform: scale(.6, 1.4);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0) scale(1, 1);
    }
}

I came across this stackoverflow answer to the same question however that solution is what I was trying to do in the first place.  I even tried removing the font size and setting the width and height properties figuring maybe it only works if you have a width and height defined.  I even gave it a display setting of block, nothing worked.  Does anybody know what the problem could be?

you already have a transform property set in .profession_title transform: translateY(30px);

yeah I thought about that and decided to join them together and that solved the issue.  Thanks
